# Como enviar variáveis string como parâmetro para chamada Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

A seguinte chamada Ajax enviaria ao PHP, os parâmetros correspondentes ao formulário que chamou a função:

```
var foo = "bar";
var bar = "foo";

function register(){
  $.ajax({
    method: "post",
    url: "meu_script.php",
    data: $("#form").serialize(),
  });
}
```

E seria acessível no PHP através dos `id`s dos componentes do form HTML:

```
$campo = $_POST['id_campo'];
$senha = $_POST['id_senha'];
```

Minha dúvida: e se ao invés de usar um formulário, eu quisesse passar os valores das variáveis `foo` e `bar`, como ficaria o parâmetro `data` da minha chamada Ajax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basta especificar um objeto javascript:

```
var foo = "bar";
var bar = "foo";

function register(){
  $.ajax({
    method: "post",
    url: "meu_script.php",
    data: {foo: foo, bar: bar},
  }); 
}
```

Para ficar um pouco menos confuso, eu daria um nome diferente para as variáveis. Algo assim:

```
var _foo = "bar";
var _bar = "foo";

function register(){
  $.ajax({
    method: "post",
    url: "meu_script.php",
    data: {foo: _foo, bar: _bar},
  }); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `$.post` documentação: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

### jQuery

```
var foo = "bar";
var bar = "foo";
$.post('meu_script.php',{
  parametro_qualquer_nome1:foo,
  parametro_qualquer_nome2:bar
 },function(){
  // ação quando for concluída a solicitação 
})
```

### PHP

```
$foo = $_POST['parametro_qualquer_nome1'];
$bar = $_POST['parametro_qualquer_nome2'];
```