# Botão Atualizar usando jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

Quero atualizar dois campos no banco de dados mas sem precisar atualizar a pagina porem estou com dificuldades em implementar algo desse tipo. Que quando eu clicar no botao ATUALIZAR  os campos Telefone e Celular serão atualizados no banco. Segue a imagem da minha tela[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1]

Comment: seu botão atualizar, é do type=submit ?

Comment: Sim, do tipo submit!

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como enviar variáveis string como parâmetro para chamada Ajax?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10664/como-enviar-vari%c3%a1veis-string-como-par%c3%a2metro-para-chamada-ajax)

Answer (score 1):

Com este código utilizando `ajax` que irei mostrar abaixo, você não terá `refresh` na sua página, mas o seu botão terá de ser de `type=submit` e também terá que adicionar uma `class` dentro da sua tag `<form>`. Segue o código para não fazer refresh e depois como terá que deixar seu `<form>` A `class` é útil, pois caso queira criar outros `forms` com este script terá a possibilidade, já com `ID` não, pois `ID` é único

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ajax').submit(function(){

        var dados = $( this ).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "nomedoarquivo.php",
            data: dados,
            success: function( data )
            {
                alert( data );
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Como você teria que alterar seu `<form>`, não se preocupe em deixá-lo sem `action=nomedoarquivo.php` e sem `method='POST'` afinal, já indiquei isto no script acima

```
<form action='' method='' class='ajax'>
```

Comment: conseguiu @olifreitas

Answer (score 1):

Você deve usar o método AJAX para fazer isso.
O Ajax trabalha com requisições assíncronas em segundo plano (simplificando, ele faz uma requisição HTTP sem que o usuario veja e sem que a pagina seja recarregada)
Segue um exemplo:

```
$.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: "sua_url",
        success: function (data) {            
            //Aqui vc muda os campos que quer mudar
            $('#id_do_input').html(data)
        },
        error: function (data) {
            //Caso de algum erro ele entra nessa função. Sempre é bom tratar uma mensagem de erro....
        }
});
```

(Apenas lembrando que o exemplo que eu dei é apenas para vc entender como o ajax funciona, pra usar na pratica vc tem q mudar algumas linhas de código.
Para estudo, segue um link com algumas explicações sobre AJAX.
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Levando em conta que você tem um formulário e quer enviá-lo sem atualizar a página você deve pensar em alguns detalhes. 
Por `default`, quando o `submit` é dado, seu formulário é enviado para o `action` definido, então você deve cancelar essa ação `default` primeiro para depois manipular os dados e enviá-los ao `script` que vai atualizar o banco

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ajax_form').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); //Vai cancelar o envio padrão para o action do form
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $('#ajax_form').attr('action'), // pega o action do form
            data: $('#ajax_form').serialize(), // serializa os inputs
            success: function(retorno){
                console.log(retorno); //escreve no console os dados retornados
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```