# Chamar link usando o Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Olá,

Eu tenho este código aqui:
[image: Código já feito]

Se eu carregar no número é chamado o href mas abre o link na mesma página, porque tem o `target="_self"`.

O que eu queria era ao carregar no número chamar o link mas sem fazer reload na página e/ ou abrir o link numa nova tab. O ideal seria fazer uma chamada Ajax, mas não sei fazer. Alguém me pode ajudar?

Já tentei o seguinte código:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'https://www.youtube.com/',
      async: true,
      success :  function(data){
        console.log("sucesso");
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

O código é executado porém não executa o url, estou a fazer alguma coisa de errado?

Comment: já tentou procurar por "chamada ajax"? vai encontrar vários exemplos, aqui no site mesmo tem bom exemplos com perguntas e respostas como essa: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10664/como-enviar-vari%C3%A1veis-string-como-par%C3%A2metro-para-chamada-ajax

Comment: Seria então seria só trocar o url no caso [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10664/como-enviar-vari%C3%A1veis-string-como-par%C3%A2metro-para-chamada-ajax) pelo o meu link em vez de `"meu_script.php"`?

Comment: Fiz um update a minha pergunta mostrando o código que já tentei usar.

Comment: basicamente isso, e o próximo passo seria verificar o que vem no objeto "data", que deve retornar alguma coisa, mas a chamada ajax em si é isso mesmo que colocou na pergunta, só não esqueça de colocar os parâmetros na url, no início da pergunta, o link manda um parametro por *querystring* na url, o "phone=455751"