# Criar um POST submit com Jquery sem form

Tags: jquery

É possível criar um Submit POST, sem FORM?

Tenho alguns link:

```
<a href="1" class"submit">Teste 1</a>

<a href="2" class"submit">Teste 2</a>

<a href="3" class"submit">Teste 3</a>
```

Quando a pessoa clicar no link, seja executado um `POST` com o nome `href`.

Com o valor do `POST` vou capturar no php e salvar no bd.

Comment: Você quer fazer uma requisição POST via *ajax* para a página do `href` do link? Sim é possível.

Comment: Exato, e só um retorno callback de sucesso.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como enviar variáveis string como parâmetro para chamada Ajax?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10664/como-enviar-vari%c3%a1veis-string-como-par%c3%a2metro-para-chamada-ajax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olha só, isso é simples...

Seu HTML:

```
<a href="1" class"submit1">Teste 1</a>

<a href="2" class"submit2">Teste 2</a>

<a href="3" class"submit3">Teste 3</a>
```

JS

```
$(".submit1").click(function(){
  var a = $(".submit1").val();
  $.ajax = ({
     url: "url do que vai ser executado",
     type: "POST ou GET",
     data: {a: 'submit1'},
     dataType: "JSON",
     success: function(data){},
     error: function(data){
            console.log(data);
      }
  }),
});
```

E assim sucessivamente para os outros dois... Caso não seja isso, explique-me melhor para poder entender sua duvida.

Comment: No caso a "url do que vai ser executado" é o valor do **href** do elemento clicado, ou seja, `$(this).prop("href")`